# Convert varchar to date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have two different table for date and time in one application. In date table "date" is stored in "datetime" format and in time table "time" part is stored in varchar format.

Both the table id is stored in transaction table for date time value.

I have an issue while querying the database specifying particular datetime value from transaction table.

Date table

```
ID_DAT          DATE_DAT (smalldatetime)  
20000101    01/01/2000 0:00  
20000102    02/01/2000 0:00  
20000103    03/01/2000 0:00   
20000104    04/01/2000 0:00  
20000105    05/01/2000 0:00  
20000106    06/01/2000 0:00  
20000107    07/01/2000 0:00  
20000108    08/01/2000 0:00  
20000109    09/01/2000 0:00  
20000110    10/01/2000 0:00
```

Time Table

```
ID_TIM   HOUR_TIM   MINUTE_TIM  STRING_TIM (varchar)  
0    0          0           00:00  
1    0          1           00:01  
2    0          2           00:02  
3    0          3           00:03  
4    0          4           00:04  
5    0          5           00:05  
6    0          6           00:06  
7    0          7           00:07  
8    0          8           00:08  
9    0          9           00:09  
10   0         10           00:10
```

Transaction data sample (id may not match with master provided)

```
SEQNUM  ID_DAT          ID_TIM  ORIGINAL_VALUE_PER  
2495089 20130424    30  10.0000000000  
2495089 20130424    60  12.0000000000  
2495089 20130424    90  15.0000000000  
2495089 20130424    120 20.0000000000  
2495089 20130424    150 24.0000000000  
2495089 20130424    180 28.0000000000  
2495089 20130424    210 34.0000000000
```

now I want to query transaction data let's say after 03:30 for the particular day.

Please guide me how can i achieve the same.

Thanks

Comment: How can we help you if you don't provide example data and expected output and what you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Something vaguely like this:

```
       SELECT * from TRANSACTION_TABLE TT 
    join DATE_TABLE DT on TT.ID_DAT = DT.ID_DAT 
    join TIME_TABLE TM on TT.ID_TIM = TM.ID_TIM 
    where (DT.DATE_DAT > '10/19/2013'  and DT.DATE_DAT < '10/21/2013')
or (DT.DATE_DAT = '10/21/2013' and HOUR_TIM < 3 and MINUT_TIME < 30)
or (DT.DATE_DAT = '10/19/2013' and HOUR_TIM >= 3 and MINUT_TIME >= 30)
```

Comment: This will not work as if I am fetching data for 3 days then for all the 3 days i will get data after 3.30.  For 1st day it is correct but then we miss the data from midnight to 3.30 for 2nd and 3rd day.

Comment: This is also not working. takes too much time and no result. Please suggest some other solution.

Comment: First of all this query is not executing (not giving any data). Next if I use this query for single day, I am not getting data for 4.00, 5.00, 6.00, etc for that day. because we r only considering minute_time >=30. Please suggest how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: can please someone help me in this.